# PHP Ajax mysql select onload

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I use an Ajax call for the select option which loads when I change the select option. I want the first option to load when I load the page without selecting. I'm using the W3schools to achieve this (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

My (W3 schools) working code for this:

```
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

  <select id="gang" class="form-control" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="height: auto;">
      <?php
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id, datum FROM analyse ORDER BY date DESC";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);      
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {                                                                                    
           $id = $row['id']; 
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?= $id; ?>"><?= $id; ?></option>     
                    <?php } ?>                   
  </select>
```

Fix was to onload on body and add an id to the option field:

```
 <body onload="showUser(document.getElementById('analyse').value)">

 <option id="analyse" value="<?= $id; ?>"><?= $id; ?></option>
```

Comment: and what error did you receive when you debugged your code? I assume you have performed the debugging process. yes?

Comment: Call `showUser(defaultvalue)` when the page loads.

Comment: I distrust your stodge code is working..

Comment: This is the w3schools code I'm using, so it works perfect to be honoust, I don't get errors. I just want the 'onchange'  when the page loads. I already tried to call the function when the page loads, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try calling it with onLoad in the body -tag and referencing your select by it's id, eg. like "showUser(document.getElementById('gang').value);"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your  tag, add below code:

```
<body onload="setTimeOut(showUser(document.getElementById('gang').value),1000)">
```

This will call your function with the first selected value of your select.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried this but doesn't work.

Comment: So, what's the error?
Did you add alert in the showUser function to know whether the function is called when the page loaded?
Maybe you need to add setTimeOut to wait for the Ajax return, otherwise there is no value in the options.

Comment: I don't get an error, I tried to alert in the function and it worked, so the function is called.

Comment: what about the "str" value when the function is called? Is it the value as you expected?

Comment: The function works perfect; but I don't want to click on the select option. I want to display the results on load.

Comment: You are right, the value isn't loaded. I manually gave the id on page load: onload="showUser('292') and this worked.

Comment: That means, when page loaded, the <?php call not finished yet.
You can simply use setTimeOut to delay the call to your showUser function. Check my edited answer. If it helps you ,remember to upvote it.  :)